# iOS 8 Beta 5 Safari Multiple Photo Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios8, photos

We have a mobile web app that does some photo uploads using the html input tag as follows:

```
<input type='file' accept='image/* name='takeMult[]'/>.
```

This was working in all previous builds of iOS safari (6.0 and greater).  Has anyone else seen this with the Beta yet?  We are wrapping it in a jquery widget and that could be the issue as there have been noted problems with jquery mobile on iOS 8 beta, but I thought they were fixed on the most recent beta. Removing it from the query widget as follows also failed:

```
<input type='file' multiple='multiple'>
```

It is no longer is allowing for multiple photo selects.  The dialog box comes up and it won't let you select images.  Does anyone have a workaround or heard any changes to mobile safari or photos/file input?

EDIT:
I've confirmed this issue on multiple devices and the iOS 8 Beta simulator on xCode 6.  I've submitted a bug report to Apple on the issue.  Beta 6 was released to carriers only, so no word if it is fixed in that build.  Still would like some feedback if anyone has a workaround in the off chance that Apple doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Same base issue (iOS filesystem), different scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to omit the `multiple` attribute in the file input element.  Of course, that will prevent you from selecting multiple files at once, but that's better than not being able to select any files at all.

There is another, older bug in iOS7, also related to the `multiple` attribute.  In that case, when this attr is set, video file upload requests will be empty (0-sized).  Don't bet on this being fixed before iOS8 releases.

Comment: Ray: The most common way i've come across to handle the single file upload is with a Filereader() javascript object.  This also fails on devices due to the way apple is changing their filesystem architecture.  I am aware of the videos bug you mentioned.  Have you attempted to use the single photo upload with or without the filereader() object?

Comment: FileReader is not used to upload files, only to read their contents client-side, which is not necessary if you only intend to upload the file.  I suspect you are talking about the File API.  User selected files are made available as `File` objects via the file input's `files` property.  This will not change in iOS8.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I wasn't clear.  When reading a single file using the File API in ios8 beta5 safari, the filereader object returns that file objects are not readable.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following.  It appears you are mixing up your terms here.  You'll have to demonstrate with actual code.  Other than the `multiple` issue I described in my answer, I don't see any other obvious issues in iOS8.

Comment: Are you running a build of ios8 beta or just assuming?  Attempting to upload a single file via <input type=file>, and then read it with filereader() in javascript will fail as a not readable filetype in iOS 8 beta (not on simulator).

Comment: Navigate to [html5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) on iOS 8 beta and attempt their 'Monitoring the progress of a read' example near the bottom of the page.  It seems that apple has either changed their file type for photos or some other issue.

Comment: Haven't tested FileReader, just tested uploading files via the File API.  Just have the simulator at the moment.

Comment: Fantastic find!  I'm sure it will make it into ios8.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is not part of iOS8 GM

Comment: I did notice that Ray, but the issue with the FileReader still is.

Comment: file handling in iOS8 GM is completely broken.  It's likely that Apple will not fix before release at this point.

Comment: Confirmed file API broken on iOS 8 release version.

Comment: Yep.  Question is, how long will it take Apple to fix this?  Or, will it ever be fixed?

Comment: I just confirmed that image read via file API IS WORKING on homescreen-ed web apps but not from mobile safari.

Comment: Yes, the issue only affects Safari, and not UIWebView specifically.  http://blog.fineuploader.com/2014/09/10/ios8-presents-serious-issues-that-prevent-file-uploading/

Comment: Awesome link again Ray.  Ive filed multiple bug reports as well and hopefully we'll see this fixed with the first update.  Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Apple released iOS 8.0.2 yesterday and has fixed the upload bug.

All file uploads are failing on iOS 8.0, for single or multiple files. All files uploaded in Mobile Safari return 0-sized [1].

Hopefully this gets fixed by Apple in the next release. It seems like it is not affecting home screen webapps though:

> File uploads are broken!! Every file upload is not working, you can select a file or take a picture and after that JavaScript will not get any data, as well as the server on a POST upload through HTML or XMLHttpRequest upload. The problem doesn’t seem to apply for home screen webapps.

Source: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios8-iphone6-web-developers-designers

[1] http://blog.fineuploader.com/2014/09/10/ios8-presents-serious-issues-that-prevent-file-uploading/

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  We worked all of that out in the past few weeks.  Your source is a pretty good resource for Mobile Web App development though.

Comment: @EricHyde No worries. If you haven't seen it yet, Apple released iOS 8.0.2 which fixes the file upload in Mobile Safari!